# Clarification on a proof of the axiom of pairing

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Sentence**:
>
> If $A,B$ are sets, there is the (unique) set, of which the elements are exactly the following: $\langle a,b\rangle: a \in A \wedge b \in B$.
>
> **Proof**:
>
> Remark: $\langle a,b\rangle:=\{ \{a\},\{a,b\}\}$
>
> If $a \in A$, then $\{ a \} \subset A \rightarrow \{ a \} \in \mathcal{P}A \rightarrow \{a\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$
>
> If $b \in B$, then $\{a,b\} \subset A \cup B \rightarrow \{a,b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$
>
> Therefore, $\{ \{a\},\{a,b\}\} \in \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$
>
> Therefore, from the theorem:
>
> > Let $\phi$ type. If there is a set $Y$, such that $\forall x(\phi(x) \rightarrow x \in Y)$, there there is the set $\{x:\phi(x)\}$.
>
> we conclude that there is the set $\{\langle a,b \rangle : a \in A \wedge b \in B \}$

Could you explain me why $\{a,b\} \subset A \cup B$, if $b \in B$ ?

Also, how do we conclude, after that, that  $\{ \{a\},\{a,b\}\} \in \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$?

Comment: Please use `\langle a, b \rangle` rather than `<>`: $\langle a, b \rangle$.

Comment: And please stop tagging your questions with both [set-theory] and [elementary-set-theory].

Comment: $x\in\left\{ a,b\right\} \Rightarrow x=a\vee x=b$ and $a,b\in A\cup B$.
So we have $x\in\left\{ a,b\right\} \Rightarrow x\in A\cup B$ or
equivalently $\left\{ a,b\right\} \subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: @drhab And how can we conclude that $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} \in \mathcal{P} \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ ?

Comment: @evinda Please take note of the proper use of the set-theory and elementary-set-theory tags. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

As to your first question, it seems that the wording was a tad suboptimal, and the assumption that $a \in A$ was carried along to the next sentence. Therefore, it was intended to read as:

> If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $\{a,b\} \subset A \cup B$.

which you hopefully agree is obvious.

As to the second question, we have $\{a\}, \{a,b\} \in \mathcal P(A \cup B)$, whence $\langle a,b\rangle \subset \mathcal P(A \cup B)$. That is to say, $\langle a,b\rangle \in \mathcal{P P}(A \cup B)$.